# GET https://myurl.com/static/js/main.c6e1854c.chunk.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: reactjs, nginx, http-status-code-404

I'm using react and nginx to deploy my website. Problem is that I deploy everything under url `myurl.com/path` but when server tries to get js files, it tries to get from root which is `myurl.com` and I see error.

```
GET https://myurl.com/static/js/main.c6e1854c.chunk.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

If I go to https://myurl.com/**path**/static/js/main.c6e1854c.chunk.js  - I can access that file.

I can't find where I should add the path for server to know correct path.

Any ideas?

My nginx

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

---

I suspect problem is not nginx as I can see parts of the web loaded (some other scripts). However what's in main js - that's no loaded, because it's missing subdirectory **path**.

Comment: I haven't worked with React, but with angular I have to put `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` in my nginx file for the routing. May be you could adapt that. For more info check https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Comment: Check the differences in the URLs: one is `myurl.com/static/...` the other is `myurl.com/path/...`. Might of course be a typo -- in that case, please fix it because it seems like the most obivious problem at the moment.

Comment: so you are saying that you have a react application that you want to host in a subfolder and when you load it the HTML is basing the path off the root instead of the subfolder. Is that correct?

Comment: @EduardoPascualAseff, tried your solution - didn't work.

@linux-fan, no typo there. `path` is my pathname.

@ShawnC. Yes. From root I host different application. And from /path I post this react app.

Comment: You need to set up your react app to know that it is in a subdirectory something like https://skryvets.com/blog/2018/09/20/an-elegant-solution-of-deploying-react-app-into-a-subdirectory/

Comment: Thank you @ShawnC. I was playing around with `hostname`. Tried this tutorial - didn't work a thing. Still my path is being ignored completely and root is being used.

Answer (score 1):

Solved issue. All I needed was:

1. Add `PUBLIC_URL=https://myurl.com/path` to `.env` file;
2. Modify all of the asset paths by adding prefix `path/`.

Thanks everyone for help and right guidance!